# Active Record default attributes (select columns from underlying table)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, materialized-views

I've got a materialized view in PostgreSQL that I'm wrapping in an Active Record class to which I specify `self.table_name = <my mat-view table name>`. The materialized view contains several columns (five to be exact), but when I instantiate the AR model, I'd love for it to only return a subset of those columns as attributes. Is it possible to define the default attributes/columns that are read from the table? If so, how can I do so?

Comment: Where's the materialized view defined? Are you using some gem for managing it (scenic perhaps)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I cannot use Scenic, because I'm using Grape API and not Rails with Railties, the two dependencies that Scenic has. I just did it the old fashioned way -- generated a migration with the SQL that defines the mat-view and created an AR model. I'm just wondering if AR exposes a method to let me specify the default attrs/columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a [`default_scope`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope) that only selects the desired columns:

```
default_scope { select(:column_1, :column_2, :column_3) }
```